# Google analytics hit returns 302 and second request wont work

Tags: html, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, enhanced-ecommerce

So basically the first hit is returning 302 and the user agent (in this case my web browser) is invited to send the **SAME** hit again to another url but this time even when im getting a 200 the hit is sent incorrectly because lots of the params are not being send. (This happens sometimes not always)

First Hit:

[image: First Hit]

Second Hit:

[image: Second Hit]

To clarify a little more im getting this problem with an addToCart (EE) and its causing me to products sales without being added to cart. I checked the dataLayer and everything seems to be ok.

So im in doubt if its a problem with my web browser or its a problem with analytics?

*If version of the web browser are needed you can read it on the user-agent of the images.*

Comment: @DaImTo Im not using measurement protocol, im using GTM.

Comment: @DaImTo EE stand for Enhanced Ecommerce and addToCart is just an event. Docs: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce

Comment: mind editing your question please and including what you are setting in Google tag manager your question doesn't mention anything about it it is unclear.  read thought this https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @DaImTo No need, i know for a fact that the problem doesn't come from the implementation since i done it in the pase multiple times and checked again and again. This problem is and i asume from GA side.

Comment: Did you get a solution for this? I have the same problem.

Comment: How did you solve it? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when I tried to manually insert the google analytics tracking code(gtag) in my .

First step was to remove the Google analytics code from the header. I had used the plugin 'Insert Headers and Footers'.

Afterwards I installed [Insights Monster plugin](https://www.monsterinsights.com/), went through the launch wizard and the 302 redirect disappeared.

I didn't really want to use a heavy plugin to resolve this issue but unfortunately it was the only solution for me.

Answer (score -1):

I copied and answer from here: https://tonnygaric.com/blog/prevent-google-analytics-from-making-requests-to-stats-g-doubleclick-net you need to do a configuration in Google Analytics dashboard.

The answer is pretty simple. Go to GA -> Admin -> Tracking info -> Data Collection -> disable both toggles and click on save. It can take up to 24 hours for the changes to take effect.